# Function that extracts bits from an unsigned int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

> Write a function called `bitpat_get()` to extract a specified set of bits. Have it take three arguments: the first an `unsigned int`, the second an integer starting bit number, and the third a bit count. Using the convention that bit numbering starts at `0` with the leftmost bit, extract the specified number of bits from the firstargument and return the result. So the call
>
> `bitpat_get(x, 0, 3)`
>
> extracts the three leftmost bits from . The call
>
> `bitpat_get(x, 3, 5)`
>
> extracts five bits starting with the fourth bit in from the left.

I didn't really know what the author meant by extracting bits, so I'm almost certain that my code is wrong and whatever it returns is not the intended return value. However, I'll post it anyway:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int bitpat_get(unsigned int from, int start, int n);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = 0xe1f4;

    printf("%x\n", bitpat_get(x, 0, 3));
    printf("%x\n", bitpat_get(x, 3, 5));
}

unsigned int bitpat_get(unsigned int from, int start, int n)
{
    unsigned int result = from;
    int bits;

    for (bits = 0; (from >> bits) != 0; ++bits)
        continue;

    unsigned int mask = (((1U << n) - 1) << (bits - n - start));

    result = from ^ mask;

    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
1f4
fef4
```

Comment: That you wrote the code is, of course, important.

Comment: @davernator that's true, it helped me understand bit manipulation better,  even though I the result I arrived at turned out to be wrong.

Comment: Very good @Areg. Also, it has been my experience that a good benchmark (instance with a known result) can help you debug the code. The probability that your code is correct vastly increases if it produces correct results on a known set of data.

Comment: @davernator of course. However, since I'm unsure as to what the author meant by **to extract a specified set of bits**, so I'm not very sure what a good benchmark would be.

Comment: That can happen, can't it @Areg (:-). If you have contact info for the author, maybe you can email him/her. A good related google might be to see what there is about the shift operators << and >>, and how they operate on systems with little endian vs big endian architecture. Very pertinent, but maybe overkill depending on how deep a dive you want to take. (:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't really know what the author meant by extracting bits.

Let's solve this bit first. Say you have a 16-bit unsigned integer, the bit positions would be:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

So the expression `bitpat_get(x, 0, 3)` should give you the three bits starting at offset zero, or `abc`. Similarly, `bitpat_get(x, 3, 5)` would give you the five bits at offset three, or `defgh`.

That should be enough to *understand* what you need to do.

---

In terms of what you need to *do* to achieve this, it's a two-step operation. The first is to actually shift the bits right<sup>(a)</sup> so that the ones you need are in the rightmost positions. This depends on three pieces of information:

- the bit width of the `unsigned int`;
- the offset where you want to extract; and
- the number of bits you wish to extract.

The distance to shift is `bitWidth - offset - bitsNeeded`. For your first case, that would be `16 - 0 - 3 = 13` and you can see that shifting the bits right by thirteen would place the desired bits in the rightmost section:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|a|b|c|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

For your second case, right shifting by `16 - 3 - 5 = 8` gives you:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The second step is to mask out the bits on the left that you don't actually need. We'll do the second case first since that has an actual effect.

The mask is basically a series of one-bits on the right, and can be obtained by starting with zero and *left* shifting in a one bit for each bit position you need. For the case where we need five bits, the sequence would be binary `0`, `1`, `11`, `111`, `1111`, and `11111`. Bitwise and-ing that with the value would give:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h| <- value
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|1| <- "and" with
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|d|e|f|g|h| <- gives
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

For the first case where we need three bits, the mask will be binary `111` so will have no effect on the original value since all the left-most bits are *already* zero.

Note that you don't need to do this in a loop since, as your code shows, you can calculate it with a single expression `2n - 1`:

```
unsigned mask = (1U << n) - 1U;
```

---

In terms of the code you've posted, I see a few problems.

First, I think your `for..continue` section is meant to find out the bit width of the `unsigned int`, based on your later use of the value. However, you calculate it based on the value passed in, which is incorrect. What you *should* base it on is a bit pattern where the left-most bit is one.

In other words, think about what your current loop will do if the value you pass in is three (binary `11`) - the bit width will be calculated as two because you'll end up with a zero value after only two shifts. So, a better way to do it would be:

```
unsigned testVal = ~0U; // all one bits
for (bits = 0; testVal != 0; ++bits, testVal = testVal >> 1)
    ;
```

Second is your mask calculation. Your code is set up to extract the bits in-place, meaning you will just set all the other bits to zero around them. It would be better to shift them to the right for extraction<sup>(a)</sup>.

Thirdly, you should be aware that `^` is the *xor* operation which, if you use with a mask of all one bits, will *invert* the bits rather than extracting them as-is. The operator you're looking for is `&`.

By way of example, using the xor operator with `bitpat_get(21, 11, 5)` would give:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|0|1| <- value (21)
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|1| <- "xor" with
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|0| <- `01010` (10): NOT the correct `10101`
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

Having said all that, I would have written the function as something like:

```
unsigned bitpat_get(unsigned from, unsigned start, unsigned count) {
    // Only need calculate this once, first time it's called.

    static unsigned bitWidth = 0;
    if (bitWidth == 0) {
        unsigned testVal = ~0U;
        while (testVal != 0) {
            bitWidth++;
            testVal = testVal >> 1;
        }
    }

    // Get the value you need to shift by.

    unsigned shiftCount = bitWidth - start - count;

    // Use this line if in-place bits needed.
    // unsigned mask = ((1U << count) - 1U) << shiftCount;

    // Or use these two lines if you need it on the right.
    from = from >> shiftCount;
    unsigned mask = (1U << count) - 1U;

    // Mask and return the bits.

    unsigned result = from & mask;

    return result;
}
```

The only tricky bit there is the use of a static `bitWidth` so it only needs to be calculated once. This is just an optimisation to speed things up in subsequent calls. If you don't want that (such as if you're not comfortable with the concepts, or if it's possible this function may be called the first time from multiple threads concurrently, causing a data race), simply replace it with:

```
unsigned bitWidth = 0;
unsigned testVal = ~0U;
while (testVal != 0) {
    bitWidth++;
    testVal = testVal >> 1;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is based on experience. It's *possible* that you may want them in-place but, in my long and (occasionally) illustrious career, I've always found it more useful to have them in the shifted section. For example, if bits 11-13 are an integral value of some sort, moving them to the right-most bits actually *gives* you the value `0..7` rather than a value from the set `{0, 4, 8, ..., 28}`.

That *may* not be the case, so the code I've provided covers both cases if you just comment out the alternate case.

Comment: *Usually* bits are numbered such that bit 0 is the least significant bit rather than the most significant.  That makes things much simpler, as you don't need to know how big an unsigned is -- you just right shift by the bit position desired, and the function becomes just `return (from >> start) & ((1U << n) - 1);`

Comment: Ok... So I understood everything you wrote (and it made absolute sense) and changed my program accordingly. However, I ran both my program and yours and the output for both cases was 0. Why could that be? I can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: @ChrisDodd so then the author's mention of the convention that bit numbering starts with the MSB is untrue?

Comment: You can extract from either end of a number in whatever way you want, but, the traditional bit numbering is with the least significant bit as bit `0` and the most significant bit being bit `sizeof type * CHAR_BIT - 1`. Think this through. If your value is `1` which bit do you need to extract to extract the value? It's just `1` only one bit is set. So do you number from the msb for the type? Or, do you number from the lsb so that you extract the bits for your value? You can do it any way you like. It just depends on what you want to check.

Comment: @Areg, check what value you're getting for `bitWidth`. If it's 32, then the top 16 bits of `0x0000e1f4` are all zero. A quick check with `0xe1f40000` would then give you the correct values of `7` and `1`.

Comment: @paxdiablo wait, so this has to do with endianness too? How would I go about making the function work for both big-endian and little-endian machines?

Comment: @Areg, that's not an endianness issue, it's just a data type size one. Endianness is just how it's stored in memory, nothing to do with the conceptual location of each bit in the type. If you want it to work with 16-bit values regardless of the actual bit width, just hardcode `bitWidth` to 16.